# <a> tag to act like a button on form without JS

Tags: html, forms

How can i make this  tag to act like a type="submit" **without** JS?

Or, if is possible, to make this a button without losing style.

```
<form id='selectLangForm' action='' method='POST'>
                      <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="HOW TO ACT LIKE A SUBMIT OF FORM?">
                        <div class="mr-3">
                          <div class="icon-circle bg-primary">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <span class="font-weight-bold"><?php echo ucfirst(pathinfo('content/LANG/'.$entry, PATHINFO_FILENAME)); ?></span>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Just use `<button>`.

Comment: By using <button> i lose <a> tag style

Comment: I solved by adding button and modifying CSS classes, thanks

Comment: (Put a comment to give you the solving mark)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using "Submit" input type?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit